# Duplicate record using join

Tags: mysql

Please look at the tables i have

**tbl1**

```
id(pk)   name
  1      test
```

**tbl2**

```
tbl2_id   id(fk to tbl1)   timein
   1       1                timein1
   2       1                timein2
```

**tbl3**

```
tbl3_id    id(fk to tbl1)  timeout
   1        1                timeout1
```

**My query:**

```
select a.name, b.timein, c.timeout 
from tbl1 a 
join tbl2 b 
  on a.id = b.id 
join tbl3 c 
  on b.id = c.id 
where a.id  = 1;
```

**Output:**

```
[name]   [timein]   [timeout]
 test    timein1    timeout1
 test    timein2    timeout1
```

My query is displaying duplicate cell from tbl3.
What is the problem in my query or in foreign key?

Comment: I cannot see any duplicate rows in the resultset.

Comment: If tbl3.id is a fk to tbl1 shouldn't the last join be `join tbl3 c on a.id = c.id` or probably `left join tbl3 c on a.id = c.id` ?

Comment: Using that logic wouldn't name test be duplicated as well?  Why aren't you worried about it?  The way SQL works is that in a 1:M (1 to many relationship) the records that have 1 are repeated for each value in the many.  Thus you see 'test' and 'timeout1' duplicated for each record in table2.  They are not duplicates.  What would you want to see for the name in on timein2? or the value for timeout on timein2? add a record to table 3 also associated to ID 1.  Now you'll see 4 records instead of 2.  1*2*2  as you have a 1:M between T1, T3 and between T1,T2:  1*2*2 if added presently 1*2*1.

Comment: the point of separate tables is to minimize duplication of data and keep like entity information together.  When you query and join these tables the duplication that was removed once again appears.

Comment: What i mean is the cell in table 3 is duplicated even there is only 1 data in table 3.

Comment: @9years Your table2 has 2 records that has `id=1`, so it will produce 2 records.  Then when you join it to table3, of course the result will have 2 records.

Comment: @Eric Oh. Joining table3 to table2 will produce 2 records. How to produce only the record in **tbl3** without repeating the `timeout1`

Comment: @9years You can't.  Your table2 contains 2 rows that satisfy the query.  The only solution is to remove table2, but you will not get your '`timein` information.